# Memento pattern with CRM plugin

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CRM 2011 Workflows: Finding the previous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211846/crm-2011-workflows-finding-the-previous-values)

How can I obtain the current value of an entity inside of CRM plugin?

I know you can get the "updated" entity via the following line, but I need to get a snapshot of its existing value.

```
 var updatedEntity = (Entity) context.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]
```

What's the best way to get the existing values? If this were a database trigger, I'm looking for the `DELETED` table.

Comment: What event is the plugin firing on?

Comment: See [CRM 2011 Async Post Update Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178824/crm-2011-async-post-update-plugin), [Pre & Post-Entity Images on Update-Plugin CRM 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281976/pre-post-entity-images-on-update-plugin-crm-2011), [CRM 2011 Workflows: Finding the previous values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211846/crm-2011-workflows-finding-the-previous-values), etc.

Comment: @Alwyn: It might make sense then to upvote those answers and/or close/delete this question, since it's more or less a duplicate (I've also flagged).